# LdapFilter not accepting Parentheses

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to match an AD contact using an email address pulled from a csv.  I am currently having an issue getting the ldapfilter to accept parenthesis.

Currently this works:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "objectClass=contact" -SearchBase "OU=PLACE,OU=CONTACTS,DC=WORK,DC=COM"
```

But this does not

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter (objectClass=contact) -SearchBase "OU=PLACE,OU=CONTACTS,DC=WORK,DC=COM"
```

And I don't know why

Comment: If it works without them, why does it need them?

Comment: .. because the first one is valid PowerShell syntax and the second one isn't. `ObjectClass = contact` is trying to run a cmdlet called `contact` and run a cmdlet called `objectclass` and then try to use `=` to assign a value to a variable without using any variables, in a way that makes no sense to do.

Comment: They are not equivalent. `(objectClass=contact)` means "evaluate `objectClass=contact` as a PowerShell expression," and `"objectClass=contact"` is a string value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LDAPFilter requires a string value; just enclose the filter you want in quotes so that PowerShell knows to parse it as a string and doesn't try to evaluate it as additional script content:

```
Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(objectClass=contact)" -SearchBase "OU=PLACE,OU=CONTACTS,DC=WORK,DC=COM"
```